# Is it possible to open JVM remote debug port only to one remote host?

Tags: sockets, debugging, jvm

I was trying to use

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=12345
```

to enable remote debugging, but this allows every remote host to debug on this JVM. Is it possible to specify the allowed remote host to connect to this debug port?

Comment: How about `server=n` and letting the JVM connect to your specific remote host with the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugging protocol is insecure, you should not allow any remote machines to connect. Bind it to localhost and tunnel over SSH, that way you can also manage authentication via SSH.

In a multi-user environment localhost may be insecure too, in that case you will also use the password authentication mechanism in addition to tunneling through SSH.